# Getting value from list of maps in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have the following list of maps:

```
 locals:
     l4_rnd:
        [
          { parent: "crm", child: ["crm-sap", "crm-sf"] },
          { parent: "fin", child: ["fin-mon"] },
        ]
```

I need to get the child details in a for_each in terraform. I need to get the corresponding parent information for the child as well.

Expected:

```
for_each(child)
 parent=parent
```

I tried this:

```
  module "l4_rnd" {
  source = "./modules/ou"
  for_each = toset([local.l4_rnd])
  ou_name    = [each.value]
  parent_id  = "ou-alft-pt1bfaa9"
  depends_on = [module.l3_rnd]
  ou_tags    = var.l2_ou_tags
}
```

I get the following error:

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each set argument
│
│   on main.tf line 43, in module "l4_rnd":
│   43:   for_each = toset([local.l4_rnd])
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.l4_rnd is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: "for_each" supports maps and sets of strings, but you have provided a set containing type tuple.
```

Let me know how to get this, please.

Comment: What have you tried already? Are there any errors?

Comment: I have updated what I tried. Thank you.

Comment: That means there are a lot of information missing.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly writes that `"for_each" supports maps and sets of strings` and you provided a list of maps. You have to convert your list of maps to a map. The easiest way is:

```
for_each = {for idx, val in local.l4_rnd: idx => val}
```

Probably you will have to modify `ou_name    = [each.value]` as well, but its not clear what `ou_name` should be.

Comment: Hi Marcin, ou_name should iterate in the list ["crm-sap", "crm-sf"].

Comment: @Felixrobinantony Not sure what do you mean. My answer addresses the errror that you reported and it was related to using wrong for_each.